# When did the term "Space" first come into use?

Tags: history, terminology

When did "Space" become the accepted terminology for the area beyond the Earth's atmosphere? What, if anything, was it called before it became known as "Space"?

Comment: I'd almost say this should be on ELL, not here.

Comment: @Undo - It's a terminology question, I think it's not necessarily suitable only for [english.se] or even [ell.se], but also equally so on [SE] websites it pertains to. Terminology questions related to [space.se] can as well be defined here, where they'll possibly be most frequenty mentioned.

Comment: Definitely belongs on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I agree with @TildalWave. It is about terminology. This is relevant for understanding old literature. Space exploration is a rather young field, so changing or adjusted terminology is a relevant issue!

Comment: This question is relevant to Space Exploration, but we lack the body of experts to *properly* answer it and evaluate that answer, as evidenced by the fact that the current accepted and most upvoted answer is simply wrong.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on another Stack Exchange Site

(Specifically, English Language Learners)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The English word *space* originates from Latin word for expanse - *`spatium`* (also written *spacium* in Medieval Latin), and later French word *`espace`*, through the use of which English variant *space* was formed.

The earliest mention of space in relation to the *'outer space'* is attributed to the 17th-century English poet [John Milton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Milton), that used it in his epic poem [Paradise Lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradise_Lost) to much the same effect we now use it to describe *'outer space' beyond the Earth’s atmosphere too thin for aeronautical purposes* (or other non-arbitrary definitions):

> *When I behold this goodly frame, this World,
>  Of Heaven and Earth consisting, and compute
>  Their magnitudes—this Earth, a
>   spot, a grain,
>  An atom, with the Firmament compared
>  And
>   all her numbered stars, that seem to roll
>
>   **Spaces** incomprehensible (for such
>  Their distance argues, and their swift return
>  Diurnal) merely to officiate light
>
>   Round this opacous Earth, this punctual spot,
>  One day and night,
>   in all her vast survey
>  Useless besides—reasoning, I oft
>   admire,
>  How Nature, wise and frugal could commit
>  Such
>   disproportions, with superfluous hand
>  So many nobler bodies to
>   create,
>  Greater so manifold, to this one use,
>  For aught
>   appears, and on their Orbs impose
>  Such restless revolution day
>   by day
>  Repeated, while the sedentary Earth,
>  That better
>   might with far less compass move,
>  Served by more noble than
>   herself, attains
>  Her end without least motion, and receives,
>
>   As tribute, such a sumless journey brought
>  Of incorporeal
>   speed, her warmth and light;
>  Speed, to describe whose swiftness
>   number fails.* — viii. 15-38.

Milton's description of the Universe and its celestial bodies is described in detail in [The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Astronomy of Milton's 'Paradise Lost'](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/28434/28434-h/28434-h.htm), by Thomas Orchard.

Comment: What is the literal meaning of the original Latin word?

Comment: @Undo - Expanse. But it would be used in any sense describing time or space (space, room, extent, distance between points, a square, period or interval of time, time or leisure, as with opportunity,...). Also as a quantitative measure, e.g. for "a lot", "much", "all", e.t.c. Etymologically, it comes from the proto Indo-European _"spe-"_ for pulling, stretching, expanding.

Comment: Both [@TiltalWave's](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/903/12102) and [@Miltonist's](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5185/12102) answers refer to [John Milton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Milton). While an excellent reference, Milton is referring to the vast space within the firmament. He also most eloquently states the Earth is at rest - which of course it is (as opposed to the modern religion of science which states the Earth is a spinning ball flying around in a vacuum). *Luckily,* @Miltonist goes on to cite even earlier references.

Comment: Oh how difficult to read any poetry in English! No rhyme ever!

Answer (score 14):

Milton is not, in fact, the first English author to use 'space' in this sense. He is antedated by Lucy Hutchinson and John Evelyn, both of whom use 'space' to translate 'spatium' in their English versions of Lucretius's *De Rerum Natura*. Milton probably did help the English sense to catch on, and he too was alluding to Lucretius. By the way, Paradise Lost, book 1, line 650 (which has the singular, 'space may produce new worlds') is a better example to use than the lines in book 8.